# PHP json_decode doesn`t work

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

Hi i want to get the personaname of steam user 
I have storaged data in files in .json format.

```
{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561198137714668",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "UareBugged",
            "lastlogoff": 1418911040,
            "commentpermission": 1,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/uarenotbest/",
            "avatar": "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/da/daece8a16d866ef9bd03ddc4aa365c5862af1c21.jpg",
            "avatarmedium": "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/da/daece8a16d866ef9bd03ddc4aa365c5862af1c21_medium.jpg",
            "avatarfull": "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/da/daece8a16d866ef9bd03ddc4aa365c5862af1c21_full.jpg",
            "personastate": 1,
            "realname": "Michal Šlesár",
            "primaryclanid": "103582791436765601",
            "timecreated": 1400861961,
            "personastateflags": 0,
            "loccountrycode": "SK",
            "locstatecode": "08"
        }
    ]

}
```

}

And i want to get the personaname to variable but it doing nothing , variable is empty
i think json_decode doesn`t work but i really dont know.

```
    $pname = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v002/?key=KEYCONSORED&Steamids={$_SESSION['T2SteamID64']}"));
    echo $pname['response']['players']['personaname'];
```

echo is empty

Comment: What does `var_dump($pname);` show?

Comment: print_r($pname); does anthing?

Comment: print_r(json_decode($pname, true)); and $pname['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];

Answer (score 9):

Players is an array:

```
$pname['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Several errors here.

Let me explain one by one giving tips to find common errors on PHP JSON decode/encode.

## 1. Invalid JSON

First, your JSON is invalid, it's missing a ending `}` at the end.

**Update**: just after @tftd comment I saw you formatted your code wrongly, but anyway, let me explain how to find issues, because this is not trivial as it should be in PHP. The other errors still are valid ones.

To check why json_decode is not working, use [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php): it'll return an error number, which means:

```
0 = JSON_ERROR_NONE = "No error has occurred"
1 = JSON_ERROR_DEPTH = "The maximum stack depth has been exceeded"
2 = JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH  = "Invalid or malformed JSON"
3 = JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR = "Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded"
4 = JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX = "Syntax error"
5 = JSON_ERROR_UTF8 = "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encode"
6 = JSON_ERROR_RECURSION = "One or more recursive references in the value to be encoded"
7 = JSON_ERROR_INF_OR_NAN = "One or more NAN or INF values in the value to be encoded"
8 = JSON_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_TYPE = "A value of a type that cannot be encoded was given"
```

In your case, it was returning `4`. So, I gone validate your JSON at http://jsonlint.com and I found the missing `}` at the end.

## 2. json_decode returns objects, not arrays

If you want to access one `$pname` as array, you need to chance your `json_decode` line to:

```
$pname = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v002/?key=KEYCONSORED&Steamids={$_SESSION['T2SteamID64']}"), true);
```

Note the last parameter, `true` for the `json_decode` method. According the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), when `true`, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

## 3. players is an array

Fixed your JSON and `json_decode` call, we can see `players` is an array. So, if you want read the first player, use:

```
$pname['response']['players'][0]
```

## Fixed Code

I'm not reading from a URL, so I used a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
<?php

$content = <<<EOD
{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "76561198137714668",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "UareBugged",
            "lastlogoff": 1418911040,
            "commentpermission": 1,
            "profileurl": "http://steamcommunity.com/id/uarenotbest/",
            "avatar": "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/da/daece8a16d866ef9bd03ddc4aa365c5862af1c21.jpg",
            "avatarmedium": "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/da/daece8a16d866ef9bd03ddc4aa365c5862af1c21_medium.jpg",
            "avatarfull": "http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/da/daece8a16d866ef9bd03ddc4aa365c5862af1c21_full.jpg",
            "personastate": 1,
            "realname": "Michal Šlesár",
            "primaryclanid": "103582791436765601",
            "timecreated": 1400861961,
            "personastateflags": 0,
            "loccountrycode": "SK",
            "locstatecode": "08"
        }
    ]

 }
}
EOD;

$pname = json_decode($content, true);
echo $pname['response']['players'][0]['personaname'];
```

This will output, as expected, `UareBugged`.

Comment: Just one note - the json is valid, the user just didn't format it correctly. The missing `}` is outside the formatting.

Comment: @tftd, fair enough (I gave you a +1). But the other errors are still valid one. And I'll keep the invalid json talk, because find that kind of error is not obvious and it should be.

Comment: Yes, that's usually easy to overlook. :)